# How to retrieve accidentaly deleted solution files in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio I have accidentally added current solution directory as a Publish directory.

The problem was that I have clicked on delete file on publish, so my entire solution is wiped out before I did a git commit.

Is there a way to retrieve these deleted files. I tried to check recycle bin, but it is empty.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You have previous commits involving that solution?

Comment: @SigmaSoldier yes, but I had a major change during the day without a commit... I decided to give it a shoot with a tool for deleted file recovery.

Comment: The only thing that comes to my head aside from what you're doing is git reset... but you you will lose all those changes n.n'